# Ensure that error messages are printed last in Python

Tags: python, exception, stdout

This must have an answer somewhere but I couldn't find it.

I would like my error/exception messages to be the last thing printed to the terminal, but it seems random whether they come out before all the text I have printed, after all the text I have printed, or somewhere in the middle of it.

I though a solution would be to use `sys.stdout.flush()`, so I tried the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    try:
        main()
    except:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        raise
```

..But this doesn't work for some reason, it is still seemingly random in which order the error message and the text I have printed comes out.

**Why? and how do I fix this?**

**EDIT:** Here is a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which behaves as described above at least on my system:

```
import sys
import numpy as np


def print_garbage():
    print(''.join(map(chr, np.random.randint(0, 256, 100))))
    raise Exception


try:
    print_garbage()
except:
    sys.stdout.flush()
    raise
```

**EDIT:** I am running Python version 3.10.0 on a windows machine, and the terminal I am using is the cmd through PyCharm terminal. My PyCharm version is Community version 2022.2

Comment: maybe you could create a quick little [mre]?

Comment: @RandomDavis good point, I will try

Comment: I suspect this is an issue with the PyCharm terminal. Do you have the same problem in a regular terminal window?

Comment: It should just be pycharm's problem: [stderr and stdout are not synchronized in PyCharm console](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-10055)

Comment: @Barmar I have not tried that, I didn't expect that to be the problem.. I will try..

Comment: When I try in PyCharm, the order is random; when I try in `cmd`, the order is always the message before the error. So, guessing it's a PyCharm console issue only.

Comment: @MechanicPig I'm not using console I'm using terminal, but might be that terminal has the same problem, thx!.

Answer (score 1):

You can print traceback to stdout, so that there will be no out-of-sync problem:

```
import traceback
import sys

try:
    print_garbage()
except:
    traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score 0):

stdout and stderr are separate channels.  stdout is a buffered channel and stderr is unbuffered.  This is why you are seeing the stderr message before the stdout one.  Python is outputting them in your desired order, but the stdout data is being buffered before it is printed.

See [here](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/06/26/how-to-check-if-pythons-output-buffering-is-enabled/#:%7E:text=To%20disable%20output%20buffering%2C%20you,setting%20the%20PYTHONUNBUFFERED%20environment%20variable.) for how to disable buffering.